# Toggle On/Off All UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios7, uilocalnotification

I have an iOS 7 application that allows for scheduling n number of UILocalNotifications.

I would like to add a switch on the app settings view to toggle all UILocalNotifications On/Off. In other words, how can I suspend all the UILocalNotifications and re-activate them on demand?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

If I do that it seems to delete them and I'm not sure how to get them back and re-activate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep track of the notifications created using some type of persistence. Flag each of these with an "enabled" status. When you "cancelAllNotifications" you should set each enabled status to "NO". Then when you want to enable all notifications again you should loop through and recreate a notification for each object where enabled == NO.

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer, but it seems so. I wish Apple would allow a way to turn off the notifications w/out deleting them. It's a ton of overhead to keep track of them!